# Landau doubting conservation of energy---and what followed

Tags: physics, biographical-details, physicists, energy, landau

When the original beta decay experiments seemed to suggest that energy was not a conserved quantity, Landau (among others) proposed that energy conservation was a statistical law rather then a absolute one. However, I came across this in an article about Landau:

> Unfortunately, the co-founder of Marxism, Friedrich Engels, had declared in
>   the 19th century that the law of conservation of energy was to be forever fundamental to science, and Landau was severely castigated in the local papers
>   for his (temporary) blasphemy.

Here is a [link](http://academic.evergreen.edu/z/zita/articles/history/landau.pdf) to the article, the quote is on page 3.

Can anyone provide a link to an article that contains some more information about this story?

Comment: Hi, welcome to hsm. This is an interesting story, could you provide a link or reference for the article you are quoting.

Comment: This was far from the first time it had been proposed that conservation of energy might be only statistical. The Bohr-Kramers-Slater theory was widely known, and it claimed the same thing. It was disproved by the 1925 Bothe-Geiger experiment.

Comment: There is a nice discussion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#Neutrinos_in_beta_decay . It turns out that this actually overlapped in time with Bohr-Kramers-Slater and Bothe-Geiger. Contrary to what you state in the question, WP claims that the upper limit on the beta decay energy spectrum was seen as *contradicting* BKS's statistical picture.

Comment: This question of BKS has some similarities https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13606/bohr-kramers-slater-bks-theory-and-energy-conservation-only-on-statistically-b

Answer (score 2):

In 1932 Landau speculated that the conservation of energy is not valid in neutron stars and appealed to the authority of Niels Bohr[1]:

> Following a beautiful idea of Professor Niels Bohr’s we are able to
> believe that the stellar radiation is due simply to a violation of the
> law of energy, which law, as Bohr has first pointed out, is no longer
> valid in the relativistic quantum theory, when the laws of ordinary
> quantum mechanics break down..

A few years later there was some ideological witch hunting announced by Friedman's article in the journal *Under the banner of Marxism* with the title "Against Denials of the Law of conservation and transformation of Energy".[2] Landau found himself imprisoned and some details of the story were recounted recently[3]; as its authors report:

> in his first letter to Stalin on 28 April 1938, the very day of the
> Landau’s arrest, Kapitsa argued that Landau “. . . published one
> remarkable paper, where he was the first to show a new source of
> stellar radiation.”  Thus Landau’s paper was used as an argument to
> save his life.

---

Refs.[1] L. D. Landau, Phys. Z. Sowjetunion, 1(1932), 285. 
1932 "On the theory of stars"; reprinted in *Neutron 
Stars, Black Holes and Binary X-ray Sources*, ed. H Gursky, R Ruffini, Dordrecht: Reidel, 1974) p. 271
[2] Ф. Г. Фридман, Под знаменем марксизма, 1937, 12, С. 192-200. [Против отрицания закона сохранения и превращения энергии](http://sceptic-ratio.narod.ru/po/fridman-vavilov.htm) 
[3]Yakovlev D., et al., arxiv.org (2012) * [Lev Landau and the conception of neutron stars](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.0682.pdf)*